# Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 + geckodriver 0.18.0 + Firefox ?? - which combination works?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm running Selenium 2.x with Firefox 47.0.2 on Windows Server 2008R2 using .Net.  I'm running x64 code.

I'm trying to upgrade to Selenium 3.40 + geckdriver 0.18.0 but I can't find a version of Firefox that runs 100%.  I'm using x64 en-US versions of Firefox unless otherwise noted.  They were downloaded from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/).

Here's what I have found:

- Firefox 51.0.1 - too old - Geckodriver complains "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"
- Firefox 52.0.2 - I get an IndexOutOfBoundException when calling setPageLoadTimeout
- Firefox 52.2.1esr - I get an IndexOutOfBoundException when calling setPageLoadTimeout
- Firefox 53.0.3 - upon exit, the Firefox window stays up, needs to be closed manually
- Firefox 54.0.1 (tried both x64 and X86) - crashes upon exit
- Firefox 55b9 - crashes upon exit

Is there a combination of selenium 3.4.0 + geckodriver + Firefox that works on .Net for you?

Answer (score 7):

This Question have been surfacing out quite often for sometime now since we migrated from the legacy *Firefox* releases to [Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094) based *Mozilla Firefox* releases (beginning with *Firefox 48*).

In general, each [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) release supports each version of *Mozilla Firefox* releases (beginning with Firefox 48) where the property `marionette` needs to be set to **`true`** (either by *default* or by configuring through an instance of `DesiredCapabilities()` Class and passing it as an argument while initializing the *Web Browser*)

If you are working with the legacy *Firefox* releases (till *Firefox 47.x*) *GeckoDriver* still works but you have to explicitly set the property `marionette` to **`false`**.

Recently, some dependency were announced between *GeckoDriver*, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and *Mozilla Releases*. The *GeckoDriver* release notes clearly states all the major/minor *New Feature Addition*, *Enhancements*, *Bug Fixes* and *Download Location* separately in this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

---

> **Selenium Dependencies**:
>
> *Selenium 3.4.0* now recommends *Geckodriver v0.16.0* strongly.
>
> *Selenium 3.3.1* better supports *Geckodriver v0.15.0*.

---

> **GeckoDriver Dependencies**:
>
> *geckodriver v0.18.0* now recommends *Firefox 53 and greater*
>
> *geckodriver v0.16.0* is only compatible with *Selenium 3.4 and greater*.

---

### Answer:

*Selenium 3.5.0* + *GeckoDriver 0.18.0* + *Firefox 55.0.2* combo works best at my end.

---

> *Last updated on : 22Aug2017*

---

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: geckodriver_versions]

Comment: It doesn't fully answer the question (although I appreciate the quick response).  So will a combination of Selenium 3.4.0 + Geckodriver 0.16.0 + some version of Firefox work?  Is there a combination that's working for you?  I'd like to use a fairly modern version of Firefox.

Comment: @DebanjanB - using your configuration, calling RemoteWebDriver.Dispose() b itself leaves the browser window up, but calling RemoteWebDriver.Close() before Dispose() causes it to crash (faulting module xul.dll).  These are the same results as Firefox 53.0.3.  I might try an older geckodriver and post results if something works.

Comment: Is there a newer version combo that works smoothly together? With `geckodriver 0.21`?

Comment: _GeckoDriver 0.20.1, selenium 3.5.0, Firefox 62.0.3, python 2_  =>   `[ Firefox ] failed: WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`, i got error result, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that using Selenium 3.40.0 + geckodriver 0.16.1 with either Firefox 53.0.3 or 54.0.1 worked for me.  I did not try any older versions of Firefox or geckodriver.  Furthermore, geckodriver 0.17.0 exhibited the same behavior as 0.18.0 - crashing Firefox on RemoteWebDriver.Close() .

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for the WebDriver close + Firefox crash problem. Do this:

> firefoxOptions.addPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart",
>   false);                   firefoxOptions.addPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1",
>   false);                   firefoxOptions.addPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2",
>   false);

Using

- GeckoDriver 0.18.0
- Selenium-Java 3.5.1
- Firefox 55.0.3

Sources:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726413/selenium-3-3-0-crashes-firefox-52-during-driver-quit-win-7-home-premium-ge) and [Github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/517#issuecomment-286375220)

Answer (score 1):

FireFox version : **60.0.2** works well with the combination of 
Gecko driver version : 0.18.0
Selenium version : 3.4.0