# Which gecko driver suitable for - Selenium 3.4.0 Firefox 48.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using `selenium WebDriver 3.4.0` and `Firefox 48.0` with the

```
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Tried with Below geckodriver version :

- Gecko 0.14 - missing type
- Gecko 0.15 - not a number
- Gecko 0.16 - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
- Gecko 0.17 - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
- Gecko 0.18 - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

`Firefox 48` is the lowest version I need to test on.

Comment: Can you check with marionate; DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Try setting the `capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 + geckodriver 0.18.0 + Firefox ?? - which combination works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w)

Comment: marionette needs to be set to true - beginning with FF 48.0 so i have heard.

Comment: as for @DebanjanB i am not looking for the FF version but the GECKO driver version that works with FF 48.0 and Selenium 3.4.0