# Which version of geckodriver and selenium standalone works with Firefox 53

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to upgrade my Firefox version to 53 but my selenium standalone 2.48.2 is not working with it.And is there any selenium standalone server which is compatible with Firefox 53 without using gecko driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 + geckodriver 0.18.0 + Firefox ?? - which combination works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions  supported without gecko driver is Firefox 47 with selenium standalone 2.53.

Comment: Great! Could you do me a favor and accept my answer please?