# How to avoid a socket timeout for selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I am having a complex python-selenium test suite to test a non-public webpage. In that setup I need to get the webdriver like follows:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, log_path = logfile)
```

with some profile and log path. In most cases this line of code just works fine, but sometimes (5% or the cases) I get a socket timeout error:

```
File "/root/tests/usecase_tests/tools/basicsuite.py", line 213, in set_driver_firefox
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, log_path = logfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 309, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 460, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 484, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out
```

What could be a possible cause of this error? How to debug this error? How to fix it?

Comment: What happens before? Probably you just shut down the browser and it's still shutting down and now doesn't want to come up again?

Comment: Probably. I shut it down with `stop_client` and `close`. Maybe I need a `sleep`?

Comment: I don't know. I don't actively work with selenium. But our tests (Java) call     `driver.close(); driver.quit();` at the end. maybe this helps

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out
```

### Sequence of events

Here is the sequence of events that happened :

- Initially the error occurs at the following line in `basicsuite.py` file :

  ```
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, log_path = logfile)
  ```
- After a series of checks finally the following method is called which fails :

  ```
  def readinto(self, b):
  """Read up to len(b) bytes into the writable buffer *b* and return
  the number of bytes read.  If the socket is non-blocking and no bytes
  are available, None is returned.

  If *b* is non-empty, a 0 return value indicates that the connection
  was shutdown at the other end.
  """
  self._checkClosed()
  self._checkReadable()
  if self._timeout_occurred:
      raise OSError("cannot read from timed out object")
  while True:
      try:
      return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      except timeout:
      self._timeout_occurred = True
      raise
      except error as e:
      if e.args[0] in _blocking_errnos:
          return None
      raise
  ```
- The program errors out at :

  ```
  self._sock.recv(b) # where If *b* is non-empty, a 0 return value indicates that the connection was shutdown at the other end.
  ```

### Conclusion

The conclusion is that **the attempt to make the Connection wasn't successfull** which means the initialization of the `webdriver` instance and further spawning of a new `Mozilla Firefox` Browser Session was unsuccessful.

### Analysis

It won't be possible to conclude the real reason why **`timeout: timed out`** occured. But you can follow some of the Best Practices as follows :

- Provide the complete name of the logfile along with the **`logical location`** of the logfile (from Project Level) as follows :

  ```
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')
  ```
- Always use **`quit()`** in the **tearDown()** method so that the **`webdriver`** and the **`webclient`** both are properly destroyed.
- Before starting your `Test Execution`, through `Task Manager` ensure that there are no **dangling** instances of **`GeckoDriver`** or **`Firefox`** process within your system.
- Ensure that the binary versions you are using **`JDK`**, **`Selenium`**, **`GeckoDriver`**, **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`** are compatible. You can find a detailed discussion in this QA [**`Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 + geckodriver 0.18.0 + Firefox ?? - which combination works?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453)
- **Clean** the `Project Workspace` from your IDE before and after executing your `Test Suite`.
- Use **`CCleaner`** tool regularly to **wipe** off the OS chores.
- If the base version of `Firefox Browser` is too ancient, uninstall the `Firefox Browser` through **`Revo Uninstaller`** with `Moderate Scan` and install a recent `GA-Released` version of `Firefox Browser`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I do not understand the conclusion. What connection was not successfull? The connection of selenium to its driver? Also, following these suggestions, the error still persists, at a level of maybe 2%. Maybe put the webdriver code in a while-try-except loop?

Comment: Updated my Answer with some more inputs. Now `webdriver` being a **W3C Recomendation Candidate** and the initialization and destroy process being **much cleaner** I don't see any necessity to wrap up the `initialization` in a `while-try-except loop`. We are in a position to deal with each error outcome.

Comment: Faced same small percentage of errors too. Machines recover after 5 minutes with no intervention, but that causes 1 test to fail in batch of ~200. I have asked about how to set a connection timeout, so we can retry more explicitly, and gotten no answer, since I need to try/catch and retry. Because, sometimes, a test teardown() will just crash, that is just life. Windows/Ubuntu/Raspbian/Mojave #selenium3

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in my Django app. The problem went away when I set `DEBUG = False` in my `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

**it's probably not related but**

if you are using vs-code on windows and you got this error just try to run from cmd, not from vs-code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).