# Headless Chrome in Python (Linux) - Taking screenshot

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get started with Selenium with Chromedriver.

I've downloaded the latest driver for Linux_64 to

**/usr/local/share/chromedriver** 
And links to /usr/local/bin/chromdriver and **/usr/bin/chromedriver**

**Python code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()
```

The file is executable

When running it the terminal gets idle. Only way to get some output is by pressing CTRL+C which the returns this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test3.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 310, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 490, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try just executing it in a python console? are you double clicking an icon to launch it? do you need to `export DISPLAY=:0` or something ... i think we dont have enough information to answer this question

Comment: What chromedriver and chrome versions are you using?

Comment: Hi! Running from console (Ubuntu server). Did try export DISPLAY=:0, same result

Comment: @alecxe ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132

Comment: See the solution in this QA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075864/how-to-avoid-a-socket-timeout-for-selenium-webdriver/48077973#48077973