# Run Python Selenium script on Ubuntu server

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-server

I have a script that perfectly works on ubuntu desktop system. The script uses headless firefox to serf the internet and do some stuff. But when I try to run it on Ubuntu server via ssh it gets stuck and do nothing. When I interrupt the script with keyboard I see the traceback below.

Server is on DigitalOcean with 1Gb of RAM.

So, I have 2 questions:

1) What do I need to do so the script will run on Ubuntu server?

2) How do I start the script so it run 24/7 and I can leave terminal window?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "cl_mailer.py", line 123, in <module>

    main()

  File "cl_mailer.py", line 55, in main

    d.get(category)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote
/webdriver.py", line 324, in get

    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 310, in execute

    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute

    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 490, in _request

    resp = self._conn.getresponse()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse

    response.begin()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin

    version, status, reason = self._read_status()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status

    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto

    return self._sock.recv_into(b)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid a socket timeout for selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075864/how-to-avoid-a-socket-timeout-for-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please show your code