# Unable to launch firefox browser via selenium geckodriver with error : Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

new_driver_path = '/Users/username/Desktop/Python/geckodriver'
new_binary_path = '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'

ops = Options()
ops.binary_location = new_binary_path
serv = Service(new_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)
```

On running the above python program i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 13, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 112, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/chetanparakh/Desktop/Python/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

I might be wrong but maybe something seems to be wrong with the new_binary_path.

Comment: FYI: this user is not accepting answers

Comment: @Prophet Wasn't using stack over flow for past 2 years so didn't check any responses.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 112, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/chetanparakh/Desktop/Python/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

...implies that the previous instance of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) is still present hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) process.

---

### Solution

Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: How do i check if the previous instance of GeckoDriver is still present?

Comment: @Chetan Usually within windows systems I would open the task manager.