# Cannot start firefox browser instance for tests using Visual Studio, C#, Nunit and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am having troubles trying to run simple UI test in Visual Studio (16.11.10) using C# and NUnit. I am using Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver version 0.27.0., Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support both 4.1.0

Test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public static void TestBrowser()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "https://login.yahoo.com/";
            driver.Quit();
        }

    }
}
```

Running this test I am getting such error:

```
﻿ TestBrowser
   Source: Class1.cs line 10
   Duration: 4,6 sec

  Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:59898/

  Stack Trace: 
DriverService.Start()
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
FirefoxDriver.ctor()
Class1.TestBrowser() line 18

  Standard Output: 
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

All works fine using ChromeDriver. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly *Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver version 0.27.0* points to the older [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) of [version0.27.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.27.0). Hence you see the error.

The solution would be to upgrade to latest version of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510453/7429447) i.e. [version0.30.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0)

Comment: Thanks, with version 0.30.0 it works!